# Access is denied. docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
PS D:\MIPTHW> docker-compose build
fork/exec C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe: Access is denied.

PS D:\MIPTHW> docker-compose build
fork/exec C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Access is denied.

PS D:\MIPTHW> docker-compose down
fork/exec C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Access is denied.
```

idk what to do, spent a whole day on solving it, but never found the solution.
Any tips?

`docker-compose` commands don't work.

Comment: Did you try running it using sudo? Also is your docker running correctly ?

Comment: It's windows, so can't access sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Powershell as Administrator.